# Stalks of the ideal sheaf of an irreducible subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Suppose that $X$ is a noetherian scheme such that $Z\subseteq X$ is a closed subscheme. Clearly $Z$ define an ideal sheaf $\mathscr I\subset\mathscr O_X$. Now let $z\in Z$ be a point  such that it is a regular for $Z$ and $X$, then at the lever of stalks at $z$ we have the ideal:
$$\mathscr J_{\!z}\subset\mathscr O_{X,z}$$

Is it true or not the following proposition?

> $Z$ is irreducible implies that $\mathscr J_{\!z}$ is a prime ideal

What about the converse (for every $z\in Z$)?

Comment: The proposition is true. Check it in the affine case. You just need to know what happens to primes when localizing a ring. The converse is false. Take the union of two closed points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me elaborate on my comment.

The easiest proof of your proposition is the following:

We have an exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathcal J \to \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_Z \to 0,$$

which induces an exact sequence at the stalk of $z \in Z$:

$$0 \to \mathcal J_z \to \mathcal O_{X,z} \to \mathcal O_{Z,z} \to 0.$$

Since $z$ is assumed to be a regular point of $Z$, we have that $\mathcal O_{Z,z}$ is a regular local ring, in particular an integral domain. Hence $\mathcal J_z$ is prime.

Note that the condition of $\mathcal J_z$ being prime is equivalent to $\mathcal O_{Z,z}$ being an integral domain, which is completely independent of $X$.

Further note that I have not used, that $Z$ is irreducible. The reason is that your assumption - $z \in Z$ is a regular point - is way too strong. The necessary and sufficient condition is that $z \in Z$ is a reduced point and is contained in a unique irreducible component of $Z$. Being a regular point implies both of this, but the converse is false: Consider the singular point of the curve $C := \{x^2=y^3\}$. It is singular, but the stalk is an integral domain, since $C$ is integral.

To the converse: If $\mathcal O_{Z,z}$ is an integral domain for all $z \in Z$, you cannot deduce that $Z$ is irreducible. As I said in the comments, you can just take two closed points, for instance $Z = \operatorname{Spec} K[x]/(x(x-1)) \subset \mathbb A^1$. The stalks at both points are fields, but $Z$ is not irreducible.

The intuition behind this is that the stalks cannot determine, what happens at other connected components.

This leads us to a positive result: If $\mathcal O_{Z,z}$ is an integral domain for all $z \in Z$, then each connected component of $Z$ is irreducible. The proof goes like this: Let $Y$ be a connected component of $Z$ and $Y=Y_1 \cup \dotsc \cup Y_n$ the irreducible components of $Y$. Assume $n \geq 2$. $Y$ is connected, hence the union cannot be disjoint, thus there is some $z$, which lies on two irreducible components. $\mathcal O_{Z,z}$ is not an integral domain, since it has at least $2$ minimal primes (the primes corresponding to the two irreducible components). Hence $n=1$ must hold.

Comment: A brief comment: if $(j,j^\#):Z\longrightarrow X$ is the embedding, the short exact sequence shouldn't be $0\rightarrow \mathcal J\rightarrow\mathcal O_X\rightarrow j^\#_{\ast}\mathcal O_Z\rightarrow 0$? Then, at the level of stalks at $z$ this coincides with your sequence.

Comment: Yes. It is pretty common to omit the push-forward, since it does not matter, neither for the stalks nor for the cohomology groups.